# Add folder contents to .rar through console commands without adding folder itself

Tags: cmd, console, archive, rar, winrar

Here's a question:

I have a folder named `Root` and it contains some files and folders. Using Winrar console commands, I need to create an archive `Root.rar` that should contain entire file/folder structure of `Root` and SHOULDN'T contain `Root` folder itself.

For example:

On drive:

```
Root-
    |-SomeFile
    |-SomeFolder-
                |-SomeOtherFile
```

In the Root.rar archive:

```
SomeFile
SomeFolder-
          |-SomeOtherFile
```

I tried to do this:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe" a -r Root.rar Root\*
```

But it also adds the `Root` folder.
Then I tried this:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe" a -ep -r Root.rar Root\*
```

In this case winrar didn't add the `Root` folder, but it also didn't add any other folders, and instead of folder tree I've got a bunch of unstructured files. Is there any way of adding the folder structure, ignoring the `Root`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-ep1` (exclude base folder names) instead of `-ep` (exclude paths from names)